# $_GET not passing to SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, get

I have page with a hyper link on it like so :

[image: preview]

When clicking on the A0000000 it will redirect you to localhost/student.php?anum=A00000000

I have checked if the actual number was being passed using

```
$get = $_GET['anum'];
echo $get;
```

this is what I get : [image: Preview]

I have done this multiple times before but the one thing that has changed is that now I am using a inner join and WHERE clauses to make a specific search. What this search must do is :

1. List a student that has counselorname as NOT NULL
2. Where finished= 1
3. And where the anum or student id number is = to the url anum using $_GET['anum']

this is the select statement :

```
$anum = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'anum', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$anum = filter_var($anum, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    try 
    {
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM inoffice INNER JOIN comments ON 
                            inoffice.id = comments.id WHERE counselorname 
                            IS NOT NULL AND finished = '1' AND anum = :anum ");
    $query->bindParam(':anum', $anum);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchall();
    }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        die($e->getMessage());
        }
```

I have tried the same query just by putting anum = A0000000 and it works flawlessly.

but when i try to do the above code i get an empty echo'd table.

Any help would be awesome! - ty

EDIT 1  : Thank you to cryptic remove the sanitizing part of the code the filter and what not and all works well. That was removing the A from the actual number part. So the query was not passing.

Comment: If you're already using prepared statements, there's no point in doing the sanitizing there with `filter_input` and `filter_var`

Comment: I had no clue :S so then whats with people always saying "get is no more secure then post, it just how you use the data"? are those the people still using mysql_?

Comment: Using `GET` instead of `POST` makes it easier for people to launch [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) on your site.

Comment: tyvm. I will remove the sanitizing. however wouldn't adding that sanitizing also make it a bit more secure?

Comment: Not really, although it might give you unintended side effects like you're seeing here. Don't add unnecessary code.

Comment: will do. Much thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$anum = filter_var($anum, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

is stripping out the letter `'A'`

Per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php#filter.filters.sanitize):

> FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT -  Remove all characters except digits, plus and minus sign.

Answer (score -3):

$anum = filter_var($anum, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

You seem to be filtering an integer which means the A0000000 will become 0, also it is a good idea to use mysql_real_escape_string on the variable to prevent sql injection

Comment: Well I'm using PDO so I thought that was doing a decent job at protecting SQLi

Comment: yes, I have converted all my mysql_ to PDO across my application.